# In a local wordpress installation, when I install a plugin it only offers me installation via FTP

Tags: plugins, ftp, linux

In a local wordpress installation, when I install a plugin it only offers me installation via FTP, even if I load the plugin .zip file from my pc. Why does this happen?
I use Ubuntu linux and apache 2 as web server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following code in the wp-config.php file:

```
add_filter(‘filesystem_method’, create_function(‘$a’, ‘return “direct”;’ ));

define( ‘FS_CHMOD_DIR’, 0755 );
```

This code deletes WordPress FTP information.

Comment: It's not about deleting the FTP information though, it's about fixing the reason WordPress needs to use FTP in the first place. Which, I'd guess, is that it can't modify its own files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement to wp-config.php above `" * WordPress database table prefix."`

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```